# Find specific construct in C++ code

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I'm looking for an idea how to find all the while loops in my huge code that declare a variable within the loop header. The problem is that

```
while ( item a = list.next() )
```

is not working correctly in xlC 12.1 : the constructor of 'item' is called for each iteration of the loop, but the destructor is called only once. This seems to be a bug in the compiler. The result was a memory leak with the new compiler.

Anyway, I want to make sure it doesn't happen in other places in the program, and I don't really know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: A regular expression leaps to mind. I don't suppose you're hip on Perl?

Comment: If the example is exactly what you show it as, why won't a regexp do?  If the example is not exactly as shown, can you please provide some details on how complex it might become?

Comment: Basically, "item" can be any class, "a" can be any name, the assignment could be replaced by any constructor ... E.g. I need to find also  "while ( xml::Node<char> node(document,current) )"